# Runnning site locally Hompage works but links don't work. using MAMP ,PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am running my site locally using MAMP on MAC OSX 10.6.8 and when type in to my browser  the home appears and looks great, but if click to move to another page say signup it gives me

The requested URL /signup was not found on this server.

But if I type

//localhost/signup.php it works.

Sorry if this is a very obvious problem, but this is my first shot as using MAMP

Kind regards Simon

Comment: in the `href` of `a` tag add `.php` at the end of `signup`. Please share html of the links.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the site is using URL rewriting (mod_rewrite). This has to be set up properly.

Comment: Can you please give some advice on how to set this correctly please, as I have no experience of doing it.